# Using conversion operator to initialize a map

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, initializer-list

What is preventing this initialization to work?

```
#include <map>
using std::map; using std::pair; using std::make_pair;
struct P {
    char a_, b_;
    P(char a, char b) : a_{a}, b_{b} {}
    operator pair<char,char>() { return make_pair(a_, b_); }
};
int main() {
    map<char,char> qmap { P( 'a','b' ) };
}
```

It looks like the conversion operator in `P` can not be applied implicitly inside a braced-initialisier-list? Or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can, but you forgot the key point: `map`'s `value_type` is actually `pair<const Key, Value>`, so in your example you'd need two conversions (`P` ⟶ `pair<char, char>` ⟶ `pair<char const, char>`) to meet your `qmap`'s `value_type`. This is one more conversion that the rules allow.

If you change your conversion operator to

```
operator pair<char const,char>() { return make_pair(a_, b_); }
```

your code [compiles](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8rG0TWd6mF2ZzpDL).

Answer (score 5):

Note that the key part of a `std::map` is const, so the type of element of `std::map<char, char>` is `std::pair<const char, char>`; the type doesn't match here. The returned `std::pair<char, char>` with braces cant't be used to construct a `std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char, char>>`, (and then construct a `std::map<char, char>` further).

If you change it to

```
operator pair<const char,char>() { return make_pair(a_, b_); }
```

or

```
operator std::map<char, char>::value_type () { return make_pair(a_, b_); }
```

the code would work fine.